# Monkey Patching in Ruby, uncatchable 'c-call' in `set_trace_func`

Tags: ruby

**Short question:** How to call Ruby method it is displayed as `c-call` in `set_trace_func` `event` argument?

**UPD, short answer:** in case of `rand` use `Kernel.rand`.

*During writing this question I found answers for particular example, but your comments are still important for more general cases. Thank you*

**Detailed Description:**

Task is prevent users use `Kernel#rand` method.
First approach to raise error on `rand` call is to rebind `rand` method in new open Kernel module. I made this MonkeyPatch.

**MonkeyPatch**

```
module Kernel
 def rand 
   raise
 end
end
```

But this solution dose not restrict all calls of `rand`.  There is the second way to call it. And I add special snippet of code to detect it.

**Snippet of code to  track `rand` calls:**

```
module Kernel
    set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
    if "#{classname}" == "Kernel" and "#{id}" == "rand"
        puts "event = #{event}"
        puts "#{classname} #{id} called"
      end
    }
end
```

After adding this snippet I found that `rand` could be called 2 ways:

Way #1 of calling `rand` log output (Catch by MonkeyPatch):

```
event = call
Kernel rand called
```

Way #2  of calling `rand` log output (**UNCATCH** by MonkeyPatch):

```
event = c-call
Kernel rand called
```

Next steps in investigation:

I take a look in the Kernel Module documentation: `c-call ==> call a C-language routine` (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func)

**Question #1:** How do call `Kernel#rand` to make it `c-call` in `set_trace_funct` event displayed?

UPD: answer on Question#1:

```
rand # call
Kernel.rand # c-call
```

**Question #2:** How do catch this call by a MonkeyPatch?

UPD: Answer on Question#2:

```
module Kernel
 self.rand
   raise
 end
end
```